# Keyboard ALT + SHIFT doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04

Pressing ALT + SHIFT is registered as only ALT, and commands with ALT + SHIFT don't work. When using `xkbwatch` I see that ALT takes one column, SHIFT takes another, but pressed together it's only registered as ALT. Doing the same with ALT + CTRL I see two columns highlighted.

I know there are a lot of similar questions but they don't fix my issue.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

I've installed *Tweaks* via `apt install gnome-tweaks` and saw that under Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout was set differently than global. Gnome Tweaks had ALT+SHIFT whereas global was ALT+SPACE. Changing in Tweaks to ALT+SPACE resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same issue
This solution helps me
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', 'XF86Keyboard']"`