# Alt + Shift + Up/Down not working inside Chrome tab Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: shortcuts, 23.04

Long story short.
I had two habits I'm not going to change:

1. switching keyboard languages with Left Alt + Left Shift
2. using Workflowy inside Chrome tab, and it has very useful shortcut Alt+Shift+Up/Down

Both worked ok (after some spells done) with 22.10, 22.04 and before.
But not in 23.04

I managed to fix the first with this https://askubuntu.com/a/1427593/1748447
But the the Alt+Shift+Up/Down shortcuts not working :(

Any suggestions to try?